# JavaScript - Check if string contain two strings next to each other from array and insert string in between

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, insert

I want to detect if there are two strings from an array next to each in an array and then insert another string in between.
So if my array contained ["hello", "there", "hi"] and I checked this string "hellothere", it would insert the string " " between so it would end up as "hello there". This should also apply if I have two of the same words next to each other.

My problem is, that I don't know how to check if a string contains two of strings next to each other from an array.

Comment: Does order matter i.e, are you looking for "hihello"?

Comment: No order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a regular expression to find as many of your words next to each other as possible. The regular expression is created dynamically, so you can pass whatever list of words you want. The resulting regular expression would look like the following:

```
/(?:hello|there|hi){2,}/g
```

The function then adds a space in between each of those words using the same word list:

```js
function delimWords(string, words, delimiter) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(?:${words.join('|')}){2,}`, 'g');
  const endDelim = new RegExp(`\\${delimiter}$`);

  return string.replace(regex, (match) => {
    return words
      .reduce((a, word) => a.split(word).join(word + delimiter), match)
      .replace(endDelim, '');
  });
}


const words = ['hello', 'there', 'hi'];
const longString = 'This is a string hellotherehi therehi hihi hihello helloperson';

console.log(delimWords(longString, words, ' '));
console.log(delimWords('hellohello', words, '.'));
console.log(delimWords('hellothere', words, '.'));
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code inside of the function (yet hopefully haha). But it seems like it only works with a space. When I use another character such as a dot, it appends a dot at the end of the string. But for some reason only if there are two different words.

So "hellohello" changes to "hello.hello"
but "hellothere" changes to "hello.there."

https://codepen.io/NoobConfirmed/pen/VBMQZR

Comment: @Tim, I've updated the answer to handle that use-case (different delimiters). You can now pass the delimiter you want to the function: `delimWords(string, words, delimiter)`. If you see anything specific that is confusing, let me know, and I can annotate the code in those areas.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit new to this. I first learned regular expressions today and I'm generally pretty shit at javascript.
So I don't really understand much of how it inserts a character in between or how the delimeter RegExp work. Also why are you using these "`"?

Comment: @Tim, I wrote up an explanation on the whole function [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhg8w5j1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
var arr =  ["hello", "there", "hi"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] + arr[i+1] === "hellothere") {
    arr.splice(i + 1, 0, "");
    break;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of two following words and insert a wanted character.

```js
var words = ["hello", "there", "hi"],
    string = "randomtext hellothere more random text";

words.some((s, i, a) => {
    var pos = string.indexOf(s + a[i + 1]);
    if (pos !== -1) {
        string = string.slice(0, pos + s.length) + '^' + string.slice(pos + s.length);
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(string);
```

Comment: That would only work for the string "hellothere" but I need it to work with "hellohi", "hellohello, and "randomtext hellothere".